# Vue dev server doesn't start inside a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

I want to make dev-configuration for my Dockerized Django(+gunicorn+db)+Vue+Nginx project, where i don't have to rebuild the frontend everytime and use vue dev server instead, specifically "vue-cli-service serve". Nginx listens on localhost:80 and will proxy "/api" requests to upstream django on port 8000 and the rest to upstream vue server on port 8080.
Docker succesfully builds 4 containters, but then vue service dies instantly. [that's what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnIVF.png)

Here is its Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12-alpine   
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN ls -al
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

(If i use RUN instead of CMD as a final command then the server gets built and the terminal hangs after webpack welcome message, but "docker-compose ps" from another tab shows no containers are up)

Here is a part of docker-compose.yml:

```
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: vue
    expose:
       - 8080    
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/home/frontend       
      - ./.env.dev:/home/frontend/.env:ro
```

[project tree, if it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74QJQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was

1. i noticed that **docker-composer ps** and **docker stats** return different results. **docker stats** showed my node container, but it wasn't accessible neither through nginx, nor through 8080/8081.
2. I added a network to include all of my containers and node container became accessible. i made changes to .env and docker-compose.yaml.

> ```
> networks:
>   service_net:
>     ipam:
>       driver: default
>       config:
>         - subnet: ${PROJECT_NET}.0/24
> ```

for node service:

> networks:
>
> service_net:
>
> ```
> ipv4_address: ${PROJECT_NET}.100
> ```